# Keep the Visual Studio publisher tool from copying .svn folders?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, svn, publishing

Whenever I publish my web application I select "only files needed to run application". Upon publishing then it all works fine except for the `bin/` folder contains a`.svn` folder. Is there a way to keep it from copying the `.svn` folder?

Answer (score 1):

No I do not believe this is possible.  The standard way of hiding a folder or file from the publisher is to prefix the folder name with a `_` (yes that really is the case).  IIRC this would break .svn and hence tarnish your enlistment.

I do want to ask why do you have a .svn folder inside `bin\`?  This folder should only contain the binary outputs of the build process and other generated artifacts.  Typically it's not the type of stuff you include in source control.

Comment: If you're using Tortoise, you can configure it to use _svn instead of .svn, which might help

Comment: You should probably delete the bin folder from SVN and mark the bin folder with svn-ignore.

Comment: The bin folder contains external third-party assemblies. All auto-generated assemblies I have within it are svn-ignore'd

Comment: @Earlz, why not create a reference folder not under bin for these assemblies and add a pre-build step to copy them to `\bin`?  This should fix your scenario.

Comment: +1 for bin not to be included under version control. One option is to keep third party tools and libraries in a separate folder (lib? tools?) and leave bin to be cleaned up and rebuilt with every build cycle.